# Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: spring, hibernate

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private xx.services.MessageSourceService xx.controllers.DatabaseDrivenMessageSource.messageSourceService;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSourceService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private xx.dao.MessageSourceDAO xx.services.MessageSourceService.messageSourceDao;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSourceDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory

xx.dao.MessageSourceDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]:

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

**APPLICATION CONTEXT.XML**

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

            <bean   id="transactionManager" 
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

            <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                  <props>        
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>          
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                   </props>
                </property>
                <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abc.cmtglobal"></property>
            </bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.abc.cmtglobal.controllers.DatabaseDrivenMessageSource"></bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.cmtglobal" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path  
resource [applicationContext.xml]
```

So it looks like you are having a problem with your hibernate configuration.
The last line of your stacktrace shows a NullPointerException.
In eclipse or InteliJ you can set Exception breakpoints.
Set one for NullPointerException and debug the startup. You may see some  NullPointerExceptions not related to your problem, but finally you will see the one that is terminating startup. Once you found the location where it happens its mostly easy to find a solution..